# MYSQL con Android

Tags: mysql, android, android-studio, base-de-datos

Muy buenas a todos, estoy realizando un login desde Android junto con MySQL para una aplicación. [Siguiendo esta guia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C1GlrrIi_vU&t=812s) he agregado el conector, le he dado permisos al Manifest y en teoria todo funciona. De echo, he desactivado el firewall de XAMPP para poder acceder desde el emulador del movil y ejecutar la petición.
Para no tener que haceros tragar un video de 30 minutos, el programa funciona de la siguiente manera:

Por medio de un PHP realizo una conexion con mi base de datos, por otro PHP, realizo una consulta a mi tabla usuarios pasandole los parametros de nombre, mail y contraseña.

El problema es a la hora de implementarlo en la APP, no se si esta fallando algo de mi código o simplemente me falta algo por rellenar. Incluso he dejado un par de logs para ver si realiza la consulta correctamente. Todo va bien, pero no me actualiza la base de datos agregando al usuario.

```
public void RegistrarUsuario(View view){
   final String Mail = mail.getText().toString();
   final String Nombre = nombre.getText().toString();
   final String Contraseña = contraseña.getText().toString();

    if (!Mail.isEmpty() && !Nombre.isEmpty()
            && !Contraseña.isEmpty()){
        String url="http://192.168.1.133/datos/ingreso.php?mail="+Mail+"&nombre="+Nombre+"&contrasena="+Contraseña;
        Log.d("1", url);
        RequestQueue servicio= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest respuesta=new StringRequest(
                Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error comunicación",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        servicio.add(respuesta);
        Log.d("2", String.valueOf(respuesta));
        mail.setText("");
        nombre.setText("");
        contraseña.setText("");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Usuario Registrado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this,this.getString(R.string.camposVacios),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Gracias de antemano y un saludo a todos.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres cuando dices que has puesto Logs y que todo va bien? ¿Esos Logs te confirman que el servidor está recibiendo los datos correctamente? Por otro lado, la acción de guardar en la base de datos debe hacerse en el código PHP que recibe los datos. Debes recoger esos datos y hacer un `INSERT` en la base de datos. Creo que deberías mostrar tu código PHP al respecto, pues ahí debe estar el problema.

Comment: Hola, en tu manifest tienes la linea android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" dentro del tag  application?? Este parámetro te permite establecer el trafico sobre http, si no lo tienes te estará rechazando las peticiones